# Zbar code ios SDK customisation

Tags: iphone, ios, zbar-sdk

I am developing a barcode reader iphone application using zbar SDK.Its working fine for me.While scanning an QRcode it is detecting very fast and decoding it.The problem is , I need to add some for features for scanning functionality.This is my requirement - > While scanning ,if a QRcode is detected it should mark with some green dots.I saw this thing in an app which is using ZXING sdk. Is there any way I can include this features to my app which is using ZBAR SDK

Comment: Read the Documentation http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/tutorial.html

Comment: hi thanks for  your comment. But I have already gone through that documentation.

Comment: what is your problem then , you need sample code to achieve that

Comment: Actullay... I need to modify my scanner such that it should marks the detected QRCode with some green dots. And yea it would be easy for me, if i get any sample code :)

Comment: i recommend ZXing https://github.com/TheLevelUp/ZXingObjC

Comment: I have tried to use zxing. But its too complicated for me to set up in my project. I am getting complier issues everey time. That's y i switched back to zbar sdk which is easier to setup as compare to Zxing.

Answer (score 0):

Do you see the cameraOverlayView at all? set the background color to red or something: `cameraOverlayView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];`

If you don't see the cameraOverlayView at all, then probably you need to set `reader. showsZBarControls = NO` which will disable the the default controls and use your custom overlay.

If you do see the cameraOverlayView, then the label is probably outside the bounds. Play around with the origin points and get it into position.

BTW I see you're not using ARC, make sure you release instructionLabel!

Comment: What I am talking about is Track symbols. "reader.tracksSymbols =YES" enabled track symbol for scanning. Its showing a green rectangle over detected QrCode. But my question is is there any other track symbol other than this green rectangle

Comment: green symbol is showing that your QR code passed . i don't know whether there are more tracking symbols

Comment: Ok. In zxing I saw other symbols, So I was wondering whether we can implement the same in ZBAR or not